How to use Quadratic Form Reduction By using Gauss's Method on $q(x) = 7x_1x_2 + 8x_1x_3 + 4x_2x_3$
How to perform the Quadratic Form Reduction By using Gauss's Method on this: $q(x) = 7x_1x_2 + 8x_1x_3 + 4x_2x_3$?
I understand the algorithm for when there's squares, but this one is particularly confusing.
The only thing I could do is this:
$x_1(7x_2+8x_3) + 4x_2 x_3$ and the then I could use the fact that $4ab = (a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2$ but that doesn't work obviously.
Any help please?

I'm not sure what Gaussian decomposition means...see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

@WillJagy Thank you for bringing that to my attention, In English I believe it's called "Quadratic Form Reduction By using Gauss's Method". I'm in France and we just call it "Réduction de Gauss".

We still don't know what that means. Do you mean by completing the square? Give us a reference, as this isn't really common in English-speaking texts.

I'm trying to write it as a sum of squares, like this $(...)^2 + (...)^2 + (...)^2$. I tried to search for an English term but I couldn't, however I found this wikipedia page in French that explains it quite well "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Réduction_de_Gauss#:~:text=En%20algèbre%2C%20la%20réduction%20de,une%20forme%20linéaire%20est%20une".

Lagrange's method (called in France réduction de Gauss) provides an answer:
$$\begin{align}q(x)&=2\frac72x_1x_2+2x_1(4x_3)+2x_2(2x_3)\\&=2\left(x_1+2x_3\right)\left(x_2+\frac274x_3\right)-2\frac27(2x_3)(4x_3)\\&=\frac12\left(x_1+2x_3+x_2+\frac274x_3\right)^2-\left(x_1+2x_3-x_2-\frac274x_3\right)^2-\frac{32}7x_3^2\\&=\frac12\left(x_1+x_2+\frac{22}7x_3\right)^2-\left(x_1-x_2+\frac67x_3\right)^2-\frac{32}7x_3^2.
\end{align}$$

Good. I have Gantmacher, I once looked up this method, years ago. Found it. English translation, Chelsea edition (1959), volume 1,  pages 299 and 300. I should learn this...The earlier question I linked  gives this as a matrix algorithm, lots of writing if by hand.  Similar outcome, denominators 2 and 7.

This is exactly what I'm looking for thank you. But could you please elaborate on how did you go from the first line to the second? I don't really see how to factor it like that.

I applied the second case of the algorithm: $$2ax_1x_2+2x_1A+2x_2B=2(ax_1+B)\left(x_2+\frac1aA\right)-\frac2aAB.$$
