Why canonicalization of quadrics using the Lagrangian method gives incorrect results when determining the type of quadrics
I don't fully understand why the Lagrange method gives the wrong idea about the type of quadric in space. I know that by the Lagrangian method I make non-orthogonal substitutions, i.e. I get at the end of the algorithm a basis whose scalar product is not equal to 0 for different basis vectors. But does this prevent me from understanding the type of quadrics? (Well, yes it does, but I can't understand why).

There is Sylvester's Law of Inertia. If you do it correctly, given Hessian matrix $H$   and construct nonsingular matrix $P$   such that $P^T HP = D$  is diagonal, then the counts of positive   and negative entries in $D$   give the counts of positive and negative eigenvalues of $H$

@WillJagy, and how does this relate to my question?

take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4919238/how-to-use-quadratic-form-reduction-by-using-gausss-method-on-qx-7x-1x-2/4919254#4919254   and my  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
